# Storing Array of Strings in Isolated Storage?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to store Array of Strings in Isolated Storage?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:
1. To store it in a file.
2. To store it as a dictionary

For your purposes, I think you should store it in a file. What you need to do is
1. Create a new file.
2. Open the file. (The createFile function opens the file for you and returns the pointer. So, you won't need to open the file if you are going to write it immediately after creation.)
3. Iterate through the array and write the strings to the file.
4. Close the file.

For more information on file IO, visit this link:
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Isolated_Storage

This explains it pretty well.

Comment: Storing in `Settings` becomes a very slow when the list is big, so, as said @Divya, file is better approach